# Cannot find where the table where the stage history for a lead is stored

Tags: odoo

The element in the screenshot comes from the `mail_message` table and show a stage change for a lead from `QUALIFIES` to `INACTIFS` but the body column of the table is empty so I suspect that there is an other table that store this information but I can't find it.
[image]

I have tried to find any table that use or is linked to the `crm_stage` table or try to find table that are linked to `crm_lead` that may be connected to the stage but I found nothing that could help.
I have tried to look into the all related table to both `crm_lead` and `mail_message` as well but none of them have any table that contains any stage_id or similar column.

Comment: I don't know much about this but I see there is a field called `subtype_id` in the `mail_message` table. Maybe you should check it whether it is what you are looking for. It is related to `mail_message_subtype` table.

Comment: I have looked in the `mail_message_subtype` table but the table only gives what type of action is related to the `mail_message`. It's unfortunately not the information I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna find out how that works you need to debug in the tracking methods of the `mail.thread` model located in the mail module

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/750d8d939b7e36cf2be810ed450e28827e871a51/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py#L498-L663

Answer (score 0):

If you use the browser to inspect the user name, you will see a div with the following attribute:

```
data-message-local-id="mail.message(id:2529)"
```

The created `message` record has an empty body, you can check it under `Technical / Messages / Messages`